# Angular redux @effect: Error on retriving the payload

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, ngrx

I'm having some problems to retrive the payload using ngrx/@effect

```
  //DELETE TASK
  @Effect({ dispatch: false })
  deleteTasks$: Observable<Task> = this.actions.ofType(fromActions.DELETE_TASK)
  .map((action: fromActions.DeleteTaskAction) => action.payload)
  .pipe(
    switchMap((payload) =>
      this.taskService.DeleteTask(payload).pipe(map(data => {
        return data;
      },
        error => console.log(error)
      )))
  );
```

> ERROR: this.actions.ofType(...).map is not a function

this is the project,

https://stackblitz.com/edit/redux-in-actions?file=src%2Fapp%2Fstore%2Feffects%2Ftask.effects.ts

thank you so much.
Andrea

Comment: What's `this.actions` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to use ofType method inside pipe function. 
For instance:

```
@Effect({ dispatch: false })
getTasks$: Observable<Task[]> = this.actions.pipe(
 ofType(fromActions.GET_TASKS),
 switchMap(() =>
  this.taskService.GetTasks().pipe(map(data => {
    return data;
  },
    error => console.log(error)
 )))
)
```

Here is fixed example: [Stackblizt](https://stackblitz.com/edit/redux-in-actions-fjb7vt)

Comment: Thank you it works the only problem is that it runs twice

Comment: Could you elaborate more precisely what 'runs twice' ?

Comment: if you add an alert inside the DeleteTask service , you will see that it runs twice, also if you check the console you can see that the http request it runs twice

Comment: That's beacause you subscribed to effects twice. In AppModule u r subscribing in line: 'EffectsModule.forRoot([TaskEffects]),'. I can fix my code later to show you exactly where the problem is.

Comment: Hi there,I am still having a problem on in for the twice call.... in meantime i put your question as 'done'

Comment: Sure, gonna work on it right now. Give me few minutes.

Comment: @Gelso77 I've updated my example. I implemented GetTasks and Delete action. I guess you will catch up how to implement editing and adding new items.

Comment: thank you I really appreciate ! it works! however my opinion is that  there is too much code for just a easy crud example

Comment: Why do you think so ? I've just remove unnecessary subscription to store  and effects inside task.component and then added 2 Actions. That's how it usually works.